# Android SDK testing - Log in into Google account without Google sign in activity (via some API)

Tags: android, unit-testing, google-signin

I'm designing API tests for an Android mobile SDK.
To enable SDK functionality I need to provide an identity token which is Google at the moment.
There's no problem to do that (get the token) by invoking Google sign-in activity, logging in there via UI interaction and getting the token from the sign-in intent result.
(https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android)

But since this is the only UI interaction that will be present in all the tests sure thing I want to get rid of it, so the thing I'm trying to find is:

Is there any way to do the same via API instead of UI logging in? By just providing email and password to corresponding methods in code.

I can't find any references to do so.

Answer (score 1):

I'm facing a similar problem where I want to decouple the login and the UI. GoogleSignInClient.silentSignIn() is looking promising but I haven't been able to check if it works yet. There's some documentation here https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/api/signin/GoogleSignInClient#silentSignIn() and a sample implementation too which looks like this:

```
 Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = googleSignInClient.silentSignIn();
 if (task.isSuccessful()) {
     // There's immediate result available.
     GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = task.getResult();
     updateViewWithAccount(account);
 } else {
     // There's no immediate result ready, displays some progress indicator and waits for the
     // async callback.
     showProgressIndicator();
     task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
             @Override
             public void onComplete(Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                 try {
                     hideProgressIndicator();
                     GoogleSignInAccount signInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                     updateViewWithAccount(account);
                 } catch (ApiException apiException) {
                     // You can get from apiException.getStatusCode() the detailed error code
                     // e.g. GoogleSignInStatusCodes.SIGN_IN_REQUIRED means user needs to take
                     // explicit action to finish sign-in;
                     // Please refer to GoogleSignInStatusCodes Javadoc for details
                     updateButtonsAndStatusFromErrorCode(apiException.getStatusCode());
                 }
             }
     });
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've finally got some time to try it.
So it looks like it won't work unless at least one Google account was already logged in on the device. I haven't found the way to pass email and password into the GoogleSignInClient. Moreover, it requires an additional configuration on the Google play services side in case the app is not published in Google Play - email that will be used for silent sign-in should be allowed to do that manually according to the note on this page:
https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart